# I'm using node/express and the pg library to communicate with PostgreSQL. When my model returns data, the properties are lowercased. Why?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, jestjs, pg

The basic question, is why is it changing the property `job.companyHandle` to `job.companyhandle`?

In my `Job` model, I have this function:

```
static async create({ title, salary, equity, companyHandle }) {
    const duplicateCheck = await db.query(
        `SELECT title
            FROM jobs
            WHERE title=$1 AND company_handle=$2`,
          [title, companyHandle]);

    if (duplicateCheck.rows[0])
        throw new BadRequestError(`Duplicate job: ${title} at ${companyHandle}`);

    const result = await db.query(
        `INSERT INTO jobs
              (title, salary, equity, company_handle)
           VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
           RETURNING id, title, salary, equity, company_handle AS companyHandle`,
          [
              title,
              salary,
              equity,
              companyHandle
          ],
    );
    const job = result.rows[0];

    return job;
}
```

My jest testing code for that function looks like this:

```
describe("create", function () {
    const newJob = {
        title: "NJ1",
        salary: 50000,
        equity: "0.45",
        companyHandle: "c3"
    };

    test("works", async function () {
        let job = await Job.create(newJob);
        expect(job).toEqual({ ...newJob, id: expect.any(Number) });

        const result = await db.query(
            `SELECT id, title, salary, equity, company_handle AS companyHandle
             FROM jobs
             WHERE title = 'NJ1'`);
        expect(result.rows).toEqual([
        {
            id: expect.any(Number),
            title: "NJ1",
            salary: 50000,
            equity: "0.45",
            companyHandle: "c3"
        },
    ]);
    });

    ... another test ...

});
```

---

So I've tried removing the `AS companyHandle` from the return statement and adding

```
        job.companyHandle = job.company_handle;
        delete job.company_handle;
```

into the model right before the return. In some of the other tests, this returns the proper `companyHandle` property, but in the first test case, it's still coming back as `companyhandle`. I don't understand why it's returning a lowercase.

---

A quick view of the jest results:

```
create › works

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 1
    + Received  + 1

    @@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
      Array [
        Object {
    -     "companyHandle": "c3",
    +     "companyhandle": "c3",
          "equity": "0.45",
          "id": Any<Number>,
          "salary": 50000,
          "title": "NJ1",
        },
```

Also, I know a bunch of this code probably isn't necessary, but I've seen too many posts without enough context, so I decided to err on the side of *over* sharing.

Comment: What happens if you change `company_handle AS companyHandle` to `company_handle AS "companyHandle"`?  PostgreSQL likes lower-case.  Using double-quotes will force it to return names the way *you* want them to display.

Comment: Identifiers need to be double quoted to preserve case. See [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: I just tried it. Still no dice. Now, it's just not working for the other tests as well.

Comment: Tried what? You need to add your revised code as update to question. Best guess is you have used the correct escape mechanism for the `"` in the query construction.

Comment: Sorry, I will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments, I made the mistake of not double quoting my identifiers.

I was too focused in on one case, and missed all of the other returns where I had not double quoted.

Thank you @Crontab and @Adrian Klaver